# Slowing rotation to a stop upon hover

Tags: css, css-animations

Right now the 'box' immediately stops spinning upon mouse hover. How can this code be modified to have the box spin down gradually to a stop instead of immediately?

I've tried 'ease-in', etc, but obviously that would just cause the animation to iteratively ease in over and over again at each iteration instead of staying at the max speed indefinitely.

```css
div.box{
  border: 6px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: turnright 2s linear 0s infinite normal;
}


div.boxcontainer{
  display: flex;
  width: 112px;
  height: auto;
  border: 6px solid red;
  animation: turnright 2s linear 0s infinite reverse forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  &:hover{
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
}

@keyframes turnright{
  0%{
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100%{
    rotate:360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='boxcontainer'>
  <div class='box'/>
</div>
```

I've incorporated some ideas from : [Smoothly Reverting Animation](https://pragmaticpineapple.com/smoothly-reverting-css-animations/)

Comment: Are you really using your second `<div />` like that? That's invalid.

Comment: True, thx, that's been corrected but it does not solve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Unfortunately, there is no one line property of [animation-play-state](https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_animation-play-state.cfm) behavior for the solution you are looking
> for.**
>
> The CSS [animation-duration](https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_animation-duration.cfm) property allows you to specify how long
> your animation will take to complete one cycle.
>
> This allows you to adjust the speed of the animation, so that it runs
> quickly, slowly, or somewhere in between. The animation-duration
> property accepts a "time" value. *For example, a value of 3s will
> result in an animation running for 3 seconds. By changing the value of
> the animation-duration property, you effectively change the speed at
> which your animation runs. **A higher value results in a slower
> animation, whereas a smaller value results in a faster animation.***

You can solve this by using `transition` property with tuning the `animation-duration`.

```
div.box {
  border: 6px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: turnright 3s linear 0s infinite normal;
  transition: transform 2s ease-out;
  &:hover {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

Please have a look on full code at this live [CodeSandbox](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/GRXovMy). Besides, you can also have a look at the link below to see both issue & solution visually: [StackOverFlow QA - Slowing rotation to a stop upon hover](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/HWyFPtZLnKU).